# Why there is an unbound variable error warning by IDE in this simple python function

Tags: python, warnings, unbound

Very simple question, but I can't find the answer to it. My IDE vs code (pylance) give me the warning/hint for `a` being possibly unbound. Why is this? How do I fix it?

```
def f():
    for i in range(4):
        a = 1
        print(a)

    return a
```

Comment: Your code is invalid, enumerate takes iterable as input you can't pass int may be you need a ``range``.

Comment: `enumerate(4)`? That's not going to work. The warning means that you should take into account that a `for` loop can run 0 times and `a` would be undefined.

Comment: @Sushanth, @Klaus I have changed it to `range`

Comment: You can add a=None before the for loop

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Because `range(4)` might be something empty (if you overwrite the built-in `range`), in which case the loop body will never run and `a` will not get assigned. Which is a problem when it's supposed to get returned.

Maybe you can tell your IDE to ignore this and not show the warning. Or assign some meaningful default to `a` before the loop.

Comment: If you assign e.g. `None` before the loop, you can `assert is not None` afterwards to get the inferred type from `int | None` back to `int` and still catch errors early where the loop indeed didn't execute (instead of returning the `None` default value).